# Why is the network not stopped on shutdown / single-user mode?

Tags: networking, fedora, systemd

I can log in to my VM over SSH, and switch it to single-user mode with `systemctl rescue`, and the SSH connection stays up.

This is not the traditional definition of single-user mode :).  Partly it's because systemd isn't bothering to stop the user session scope units in single-user mode.  (It does stop gdm and hence GNOME though, and gettys, so it  will send SIGHUP to any text console sessions).

But it's also not traditional to leave the network running in single-user mode!  How does that part happen?

The VM is Fedora 26 Workstation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetworkManager deliberately doesn't stop networking on shutdown.  Because it supports taking over ("managing") network devices which were started by the system network configuration system, e.g. ifcfg on Fedora, ifupdown on Debian.  It leaves the system to stop them as well.

However Fedora now considers ifcfg to be legacy, and does not enable it by default.  Therefore the *stop* script never runs either.